# Create Android.mk to build a C library

Tags: android, build, java-native-interface, android-ndk

I'm developping an app which needs to use a Java library (jpcap: http://netresearch.ics.uci.edu/kfujii/Jpcap/doc/download.html). The problem is that library uses JNI to call methods written in C code.

In order to call correctly the Java methods I have to compile the C code of the library using the Android NDK. To compile the C code I have to write an Android.mk file to use it with the ndk-build script which provides the NDK.

I've never written before an Android.mk and I don't know how to write the file to fit my needs which are the next:

**Compile the following source files:**

JpcapCaptor.c
JpcapSender.c
JpcapWriter.c
packet_arp.c
packet_datalink.c
packet_icmp.c
packet_ip.c
packet_ipv6.c
packet_tcp.c
packet_udp.c

**Include the following libraries:**

jni.h
pcap.h

**Link using the -lpcap option.**

If any of you guys could tell me which lines do I have to write in the Android.mk file or tell me where to find a manual which explains this I would be very thankfull.

Comment: Jimix, could you compile jpcap library with Android NDK  ???

Answer (score 0):

Try using this :

```
LOCAL_PATH:= $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $$Add source files$$

LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lpcap

LOCAL_MODULE := libtest

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := $$Path of the header files used$$

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: I'm getting errors when compiling: "dereferencing pointer to incomplete type".

Comment: Please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943828/how-to-compile-a-static-library-using-the-android-ndk for more details.