# Error in creating .SO file using Cygwin

Tags: android, c++, c, opencv, android-ndk

I am trying to create .so files using Cygwin for my Android ndk application. But Cygwin terminal is showing following errors.

```
$ /cygdrive/c/native_work/android-ndk-r8b/ndk-build
Cygwin         : Generating dependency file converter script
Compile++ thumb  : main <= main.cpp
In file included from jni/NotePaperDetector.hpp:4:0,
             from jni/main.cpp:1:
jni/NoteLocation.hpp:4:30: fatal error: opencv2/opencv.hpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/cygdrive/c/native_work/android-ndk-r8b/build/core/build-binary.mk:255: recipe for         target `obj/local/armeabi/objs/main  /main.o' failed
make: *** [obj/local/armeabi/objs/main/main.o] Error 1
```

I have the following files in my jni folder -

```
NotePaperDetector.hpp 
NotePaperDetector.cpp 
NoteDescription.hpp 
NoteDescription.cpp 
NoteLocation.hpp 
NoteLocation.cpp 
ImageUtils.hpp
ImageUtils.cpp
MarkerCandidate.hpp
MarkerCandidate.cpp
main.cpp
```

Android.mk file is -

```
  LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

# Here we give our module name and source file(s)
LOCAL_MODULE    := main
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
 
    include $(CLEAR_VARS)
 
     # Here we give our module name and source file(s)
     LOCAL_MODULE    := main
     LOCAL_SRC_FILES := main.cpp
 
     include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106965/how-to-link-any-libarary-in-ndk-application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The system cannot find path to OpenCV installation. You need to add `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` variable to Android.mk pointing to the `OpenCV` folder, i.e:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../opencv
```

Comment: Note that `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES` lists _directories_ relative to the current directory of **make**, usually the Android project directory, with the `ApplicationManifest.mk` file, while the `LOCAL_SRC_FILES` lists _files_ relative to the `LOCAL_PATH`, usually named `jni`. You can also use absolute paths in `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES`, e.g. `/cygdrive/c/downloads/opencv`

Comment: You cannot use /cygdrive/ if you are developing in a Cygwin-less environment on Windows.

Comment: You are right, and NDK-r8b can luckily be used without Cygwin. I believe that with or without Cygwin, `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += c:/downloads/opencv` will work. But the question explicitly speaks about Cygwin environment, that's why I formatted the path this way.

Comment: Sure, but there is a portable way of using relative paths with many ".."

Comment: Actually I have to use Open CV in my application with some native code to Image Recognization through Camera. Can you please suggest how I need to add that library and create make file.

Comment: Here you go: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106965/how-to-link-any-libarary-in-ndk-application

Comment: **Meta-discussion** [@Sergey K.](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1065190/sergey-k"): _there is a portable way of using relative paths with many ".."_ - I beg to differ. The problem is that in `Android.mk` we don't have a guaranteed _current directory_. It may be included in a project (or in different projects) in various ways, leading to inconsistent relative paths. Luckily, `LOCAL_PATH` is guaranteed. Therefore, I prefer setting `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../../something` instead of `LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += ../../something`, even though usually these two are equivalent.

Comment: We can use ``LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)`` to get the directory. I have updated the answer.