# AOSP 5.1 - how can I execute my app with real-root rights?

Tags: java, android, android-source, su, android-5.1.1-lollipop

In my **AOSP 5.1-build**, I am trying to create a `MySetupApp.apk`-app, that does some setup-actions according to the user.
 E.g. among other things (that mostly also require root) the user should be able to select a bootanimation in my `MySetupApp.apk`. The bootanimation is saved on `/sdcard/` and the apk should move it to the correct system-folder `/system/media/bootanimation.zip`
This is working fine on the adb-shell. The following commands deliver the desired result (new bootanimation):

```
adb remount
adb shell cp /sdcard/bootanimation.zip /system/media/
adb shell chmod 777 /system/media/bootanimation.zip
```

---

The app is running as system-user:
`android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system"` I can verify this on the adb-shell:

```
root@astar-yh:/system/bin # ps
system    9634  170   1242144 35536 ffffffff b6e51bf4 S com.mycompany.MySetupApp
```

I have added the app in my AOSP-build:

**`/android/device/softwinner/common/prebuild/apk/Android.mk`**:

```
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := MySetupApp
LOCAL_MODULE_TAGS := optional
LOCAL_CERTIFICATE := platform
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := APPS
LOCAL_MODULE_SUFFIX := $(COMMON_ANDROID_PACKAGE_SUFFIX)
LOCAL_PRIVILEGED_MODULE := true
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(LOCAL_MODULE).apk
include $(BUILD_PREBUILT)
```

So the app is installed in `/system/priv-app` and is signed with the platform-keys.

Also I have tweaked **`/android/system/extras/su/su.c`**:

```
myuid = getuid();
// added AID_SYSTEM
if (myuid != AID_ROOT && myuid != AID_SHELL && myuid != AID_SYSTEM) {
   fprintf(stderr,"su: uid %d not allowed to su\n", myuid);
   return 1;
}

// Removed this code-block
/*if(setgid(gid) || setuid(uid)) {
    fprintf(stderr,"su: permission denied\n");
    return 1;
}*/
```

Here is my Java-Code. The outputs are in comments behind the lines:

```
public void doRootStuff(){
  try {
    String line;
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");

    OutputStream stdin = process.getOutputStream();
    InputStream stderr = process.getErrorStream();
    InputStream stdout = process.getInputStream();

    stdin.write(("getenforce\n").getBytes()); // "Permissive"
    stdin.write(("mount -o rw,remount -t ext4 /system\n").getBytes()); //E/[Error]: mount: Operation not permitted
    stdin.write(("ls /data/data/\n").getBytes()); // Works! Shows the directory contents
    stdin.write(("touch /system/media/test\n").getBytes()); // Does nothing - no error but also no file
    stdin.write(("cp -f /sdcard/bootanimation.zip /system/media/bootanimation_test.zip\n").getBytes()); // E/[Error]: cp: /system/media/bootanimation_test.zip: Read-only file system
    stdin.write("exit\n".getBytes());
    stdin.flush();

    stdin.close();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      Log.d("[Output]", line);
    }
    br.close();
    br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stderr));
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
      Log.e("[Error]", line);
    }
    br.close();
    process.waitFor();
    process.destroy();

  } catch (Exception ex) {
    Log.e(TAG, ex.toString());
    ex.printStackTrace();
  }
}
```

As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13802869/how-to-modify-aosp-to-allow-specific-apps-to-get-root-access), I have also edited the `android_filesystem_config.h`, but without any luck

```
    { 06755, AID_ROOT,      AID_ROOT,      0, "system/priv-app/MySetupApp/*" },
```

Calling `setuid(0);` in my app also doesn't work:

```
com.mycompany.MySetupApp W/art: Failed to find OatDexFile for DexFile /system/priv-app/MySetupApp/MySetupApp.apk ( canonical path /system/priv-app/MySetupApp/MySetupApp.apk) with checksum 0x73b2ee8d in OatFile /data/dalvik-cache/arm/system@priv-app@MySetupApp@MySetupApp.apk@classes.dex
com.mycompany.MySetupApp W/System.err: android.system.ErrnoException: setuid failed: EPERM (Operation not permitted)
```

---

So remounting the system-directory and copying something on it is not possible from the apk!

**What can I do, to make this work? What should I change in my app or in the Android-Sources?**

#### Update

I also tried to transfer the functionality into a script `setup_device.sh` and put it into `/system/bin/setup_script.sh`. When I try to run this in java:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su");
stdin.write(("./system/bin/setup_device.sh\n").getBytes());
```

it says:

```
E/[Error]: sh: <stdin>[2]: ./system/bin/setup_device.sh: Permission denied
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to resolve my issue:

### 1.) As mentioned in the question I wrote a simple script, that copies the bootanimation from `/sdcard/` to `/system/media/`. Put this script into `/system/bin/`

**`setup_device.sh`**

```
#!/sbin/busybox sh

BUSYBOX="/sbin/busybox"

echo "Remount /system-partition to rw"
mount -o remount,rw /system

if [ -e /sdcard/bootanimation.zip ] ; then
    echo "copy bootanimation"
    $BUSYBOX cp -fp "/sdcard/bootanimation.zip" "/system/media/bootanimation.zip"
    chmod 777 "/system/media/bootanimation.zip"
    chown 0.0 "/system/media/bootanimation.zip"
    $BUSYBOX rm "/sdcard/bootanimation.zip"
else
    echo "Bootanimation not in /sdcard/-folder"
fi
```

### 2.) Invoke this script in  [`init.rc`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/master/init/README.md) and execute it on property-change

```
service setup_device /sbin/busybox sh /system/bin/setup_device.sh
    user root
    group root
    disabled
    oneshot

on property:start.setup=1
    start setup_device
```

### 3.) In the setup.apk, Just set this property:

```
Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "/system/bin/sh", "-c", "setprop start.setup 1" });
proc.waitFor();
```

Right after the app sets this property, the `setup_device.sh`-script will trigger and execute the code with **root-rights**!
`bootanimation.zip` will finally copy to `/system/media/` and you can see the new bootanmiation as soon as you reboot the device.

#### Pitfalls:

- When you declare the script-name in init.rc, be sure that is does not exceed the character-limit of 16 characters! Also only user alpha-numerical characters and `-` or `_`