# Use created .so file in another application - Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have used android - ndk - r8 and followed the [LINK](http://trivedihardik.wordpress.com/2011/06/16/hello-world-example-using-ndk-in-android/) to create a .so library. Now my aim is to use this library in another project. Instead of copying the complete source there i just want to use the library. I tried to copy & paste the whole libs/armeabi/libAddition.so library to the project root of the another application but the app crashes when i use these library in other application. The library consists of simple addtion of two number logic.

**NOTE** Their is no error in application or the .so file and the error in error log is unsatisfiedlinkerror. 
Also i dont want to create a library project or anything else i just need to use these .so file in my another project.

So what would be the best way to do it? I am using Eclipse.

Comment: Check this answer

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10593987/android-ndk-linking/10615769#10615769

Comment: The following answers should help solve your question (in combination): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165813/using-my-own-prebuilt-shared-library-in-an-android-ndk-project http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10106965/how-to-link-any-libarary-in-ndk-application http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10363021/multiple-my-and-3rd-party-native-libraries-in-android-ndk/10367658

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to your .so.  There is the actual C library you want to use and then there is the JNI glue code.  I would bet the reason that your app is crashing is because the JNI is referencing the package name from your previous application.  If you want to create a library that you can use over and over you need to create the library and the JNI separately.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165813/using-my-own-prebuilt-shared-library-in-an-android-ndk-project) post may be useful.
I tried it and it worked for me but only if I called System.loadLibrary from the same package name. Otherwise it thrown an UnsatisfiedLinkError but I didn't looked deeper to know what was wrong.