# Cross-compiling a C library for Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface, cross-compiling

I'm a bit confused with what I'm currently attempting: I want to cross-compile a C library for use with Android through the NDK, so that I can create a JNI wrapper and call some of its functions from my Android java code.

- I followed this guide to crosscompile libopus (the library I want to include in my project): http://mortoray.com/2012/08/21/android-ndk-cross-compile-setup-libpng-and-freetype/ which means **I currently have a standalone toolchain at /opt/android-ext/, with a lib folder that contains the library I cross-compiled (libopus.a, libopus.so, etc)**.
- I also already have a jni folder on my Android project, which contains some C code with the JNI bindings that I want, and that I can call from my Java code, but it does nothing (I can call it but it's a blank function). This means that in my project, there's a /lib/armeabi directory with "libopusUtilsNative.so" (the wrapper).

My question is:

How do I add the library that I just crosscompiled to the project, so that (for example) I can just do an #include call on the C source code file that I already have and get access to the library functions? I'm a bit lost with how to:

1. Include the library I cross-compiled into my project.
2. How to make the wrapper code I created include it (I'm guessing this has something to do with adding some code to my Android.mk file, but I'm clueless).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The guide that you linked to contains an example of how to modify the Android.mk file for your JNI library (or in his case, a native app) to link against the cross-compiled library:

```
PLATFORM_PREFIX := /opt/android-ext/

LOCAL_PATH := $(PLATFORM_PREFIX)/lib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libpng
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libpng.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# The in your project add libpng
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue libpng
```

That's pretty much how you'd do it if you wanted to link statically against libopus. Or if you want to link against the shared library, use something like this: [Using my own prebuilt shared library in an Android NDK project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165813/using-my-own-prebuilt-shared-library-in-an-android-ndk-project)

Comment: Yes, however I'm not sure how to add that bit to my already-existing Android.mk. For example, in my Android.mk, the LOCAL_PATH variable is already defined as $(call my-dir). If I just copy-paste it into my existing Android.mk, won't that be an issue?

Comment: Well, if you want to you could probably remove that `LOCAL_PATH` assignment from the above makefile snippet and specify the full path of the lib in `LOCAL_SRC_FILES`.

Comment: It seems to have worked... to a degree. Here's my current issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14325440/undefined-reference-to-function-in-static-library-with-ndk