# Undefined reference to function in static library with NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk

So I'm attempting to use libopus on my native code for an Android application.
My Android.mk file looks like this:

```
PLATFORM_PREFIX := /opt/android-ext/
LOCAL_PATH := $(PLATFORM_PREFIX)/lib

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := libopus
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := libopus.a

include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)

# I have to redeclare LOCAL_PATH because the library is in /opt/android-ext/
# and my project is somewhere else. Not very elegant.

LOCAL_PATH := /home/sergio/workspace/Project/jni

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := opusUtilsNative
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := opusUtilsNative.c
LOCAL_C_INCLUDES += $(PLATFORM_PREFIX)/include
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := android_native_app_glue libopus

include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

And my code in opusUtilsNative.c looks like this:

```
#include "opusUtilsNative.h"
#include <opus/opus.h>
#include <opus/opus_types.h>

JNIEXPORT jbyteArray JNICALL Java_Project_OpusUtils_encode
  (JNIEnv * je, jclass jc, jbyteArray data){

    int rc;
    opus_int16 * testOutBuffer;
    unsigned char* opusBuffer;

    OpusDecoder *dec;

    dec = opus_decoder_create(48000, 2, &rc);
    return data;
}
```

And when I try to build it, it works fine **only if I remove the line that uses the "opus_decoder_create" function**. Else I will get this:

```
error: undefined reference to 'opus_decoder_create'
```

I can see that opus_decoder_create is clearly defined on opus.h, which is clearly being included since if I exclude that line, I'll get an error regarding the opus_int16 and OpusDecoder declarations. How come some definitions are being included and some aren't?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This was tricky. After digging around for a bit, I realized I hadn't cross-compiled the opus library correctly, and I didn't have an ARM binary after all.

A good way to verify if your library was cross-compiled correctly:

```
cd /opt/android-ext/lib #Or wherever the .a file is
ar x libopus.a
file tables_LTP.o #Or any of the .o files generated by ar x
```

The output should look like this:

```
tables_LTP.o: ELF 32-bit LSB relocatable, ARM, version 1 (SYSV), not stripped
```

Otherwise, you might want to double-check your cross-compilation process.

Comment: Do you perhaps also know how to compile it cross-platform on Windows? I am experiencing the same error as you, but I am using Visual Studio 2015 + Cross-Platform Tools and clang and NDK.

Answer (score 0):

It's error from linker, not from compiler. You forgot to add reference to correspondent libraries to your `Android.mk` file, do smth like this:

```
LOCAL_LDLIBS += -lopus
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot to integrate one key library

## LOCAL_LDLIBS := -lGLESv2

This fixed my problem.