# Add static lib(file .lib) in .pro to compile a application Qt/Android

Tags: qt, static-libraries, protocol-buffers, log4qt

I have a problem to compile a project Qt/Android, because of the use of some static libs(windows .lib). The current situation of .pro file is this:

```
android {
    QT += androidextras
    ANDROID_PACKAGE_SOURCE_DIR = $$PWD/native
    ANDROID_DEPLOYMENT_DEPENDENCIES = \
           $$PWD/../../../libraries/protobuf/vsprojects/Release/libprotobuf.lib \
           $$PWD/../../../libraries/log4qt/lib/liblog4qtd.lib
}
```

However this not solve the problems, i not know what make =/

Comment: Compile or deploy? AFAIK that `QMake` flag is used to insert libraries in the final APK. Native libraries in Android have extension `.so` or `.a`. You should provide a compatible version, i.e. cross-compile the library for Android.

Comment: Yes, this flag is used to add native libraries .so/.jar(not know about the .a) -- really i not know how to solve this problem =/

These problems happen during the compilation

Comment: `.so` are dynamic libs, `.a` are static libs (much like `dll`/`lib` in Win). A `lib` is a Windows static library. `.so`, `.a` and `.jar` libraries are valid libraries for Android (`.jar` is not strictly "native"). [Compile your static libs for Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2943828/how-to-compile-a-static-library-using-the-android-ndk). Or search for a downloadable version for Android. That's it.

Comment: Compile the libs with ndk solved the problem ... Thanks for the help ...