# Cannot ndk-build a static library with gnustl_shared

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, ndk-build

I want to build a static library, say libstatic.a, linking with gnustl_shared

static.hpp

```
namespace Static {
  void func();
}
```

static.cpp

```
#include "static.hpp"
#include <iostream>

namespace Static {
  void func() {
    std::cout << "Static::func()." << std::endl;
  }
}
```

Android.mk

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := libstatic
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := static.cpp
include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Application.mk

```
NDK_TOOLCHAIN_VERSION := 4.9
APP_ABI := x86_64
APP_STL := gnustl_shared
APP_PLATFORM := android-21
APP_CPPFLAGS := -std=c++11 -frtti -fexceptions
APP_OPTIM := debug
```

I run ndk-build and only libgnustl_shared.so is copied. No static library is generated.

```
[x86_64] Prebuilt       : libgnustl_shared.so <= <NDK>/sources/cxx-stl/gnu-libstdc++/4.9/libs/x86_64/
[x86_64] Install        : libgnustl_shared.so => libs/x86_64/libgnustl_shared.so
```

Directory structure

```
├── jni
│   ├── Android.mk
│   ├── Application.mk
│   ├── static.cpp
│   └── static.hpp
```

Anyone has any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: Have you checked the `obj/local` subdirectories? What if you insert something in `static.cpp` that isn't valid C++? Do you get a compilation error then?

Comment: Is that the full output of the ndk-build command? If not, will you edit the post to show the full output?

Comment: @Michael No compilation error. Looks like ndk not trying to compile static.cpp!

Comment: @MartinK.Brown Yes, that's the full output.

Comment: What does your directory structure look like, and what files are in the directories?

Comment: @MartinK.Brown Updated. Actually I think the directory structure is OK because if I used BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY everything is fine.

Comment: @cck Try this http://stackoverflow.com/a/22172651/1445466

Comment: @MartinK.Brown Thanks a lot! It works!

Comment: @cck You're welcome. How about saying thanks with an upvote on that comment as well?

Comment: @MartinK.Brown I'd love to, but my reputation...